# how to make addToCart function in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on my laravel project. It is on Laravel 9. I need your help, please write to me add to cart logic, i know to search in google. I researched but did not find example for my code. Next i started editing but nothing comes. So, i need your help guys. I have table products in database which have title, price, description, image.

This is my shop.blade.php :

```
                        <div class="text-center py-4">
                            <a class="h6 text-decoration-none text-truncate" href="http://localhost/e-commerce/public/shop/{{$product->id}}">{{$product->title}}</a>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mt-2">
                                <h5>{{$product->price}}$</h5><h6 class="text-muted ml-2"><del>{{$product->old_price}}$</del></h6>
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-1">
                                <small class="fa fa-star text-primary mr-1"></small>
                                <small class="fa fa-star text-primary mr-1"></small>
                                <small class="fa fa-star text-primary mr-1"></small>
                                <small class="fa fa-star text-primary mr-1"></small>
                                <small class="fa fa-star text-primary mr-1"></small>
                                <small>(99)</small>
                            </div>
                            <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Cart</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

please help me

Comment: You need to put in more effort. First google result: https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart

Answer (score 0):

You can create new table to save information, this table should contain product_id and user_id, when you press add_to_cart button you have to insert new row to the table, and by using laravel's belongsToMany relationship you can show products in cart page. It will be like this

```
App\Models\Product;
public function products_in_cart() {
  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, "products_in_carts(this will be table name)", "product_id", "user_id");
}
```

Comment: and, i have one question,  i shoul make add to cart with sessions or using database

Comment: which is right way?

Comment: im providing a complete example, adapt it to your needs

Comment: and which is the right way?

Comment: It depends on project I think, but more right way would be to save in cookies if user is not logged in, and in database if user has logged in. If you are not using Authentication then just save it in cookies or session

Comment: see response below, if you are starting just use the DB, later on you can jump to Redis, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do some google resarch. I would strongly suggest to use session (Redis) to storage, below some relevant code adatable to your needs, hope it helps.
Sample source from: [Laravel Shopping Cart](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-shopping-add-to-cart-with-ajax-exampleexample.html)

1- app/Models/Products.php

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Models;
   
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
  
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price', 'description', 'image'
    ];
}
```

2-app/Http/Controllers/ProductController.php

```
<?php
  
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;
  
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('products', compact('products'));
    }
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function cart()
    {
        return view('cart');
    }
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function addToCart($id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
          
        $cart = session()->get('cart', []);
  
        if(isset($cart[$id])) {
            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;
        } else {
            $cart[$id] = [
                "name" => $product->name,
                "quantity" => 1,
                "price" => $product->price,
                "image" => $product->image
            ];
        }
          
        session()->put('cart', $cart);
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Product added to cart successfully!');
    }
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->id && $request->quantity){
            $cart = session()->get('cart');
            $cart[$request->id]["quantity"] = $request->quantity;
            session()->put('cart', $cart);
            session()->flash('success', 'Cart updated successfully');
        }
    }
  
    /**
     * Write code on Method
     *
     * @return response()
     */
    public function remove(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->id) {
            $cart = session()->get('cart');
            if(isset($cart[$request->id])) {
                unset($cart[$request->id]);
                session()->put('cart', $cart);
            }
            session()->flash('success', 'Product removed successfully');
        }
    }
}
```

3-resources/views/layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel Add To Cart Function - ItSolutionStuff.com</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
    <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 main-section">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cart <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ count((array) session('cart')) }}</span>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <div class="row total-header-section">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6">
                            <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">{{ count((array) session('cart')) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        @php $total = 0 @endphp
                        @foreach((array) session('cart') as $id => $details)
                            @php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] @endphp
                        @endforeach
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-6 total-section text-right">
                            <p>Total: <span class="text-info">$ {{ $total }}</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @if(session('cart'))
                        @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
                            <div class="row cart-detail">
                                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-4 cart-detail-img">
                                    <img src="{{ $details['image'] }}" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 col-8 cart-detail-product">
                                    <p>{{ $details['name'] }}</p>
                                    <span class="price text-info"> ${{ $details['price'] }}</span> <span class="count"> Quantity:{{ $details['quantity'] }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endforeach
                    @endif
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-12 text-center checkout">
                            <a href="{{ route('cart') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">View all</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
<br/>
<div class="container">
  
    @if(session('success'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
          {{ session('success') }}
        </div> 
    @endif
  
    @yield('content')
</div>
  
@yield('scripts')
     
</body>
</html>
```

4-resources/views/products.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
   
@section('content')
    
<div class="row">
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <div class="col-xs-18 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img src="{{ $product->image }}" alt="">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>{{ $product->name }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ $product->description }}</p>
                    <p><strong>Price: </strong> {{ $product->price }}$</p>
                    <p class="btn-holder"><a href="{{ route('add.to.cart', $product->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-center" role="button">Add to cart</a> </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
    
@endsection
```

5-resources/views/cart.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')
  
@section('content')
<table id="cart" class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width:50%">Product</th>
            <th style="width:10%">Price</th>
            <th style="width:8%">Quantity</th>
            <th style="width:22%" class="text-center">Subtotal</th>
            <th style="width:10%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php $total = 0 @endphp
        @if(session('cart'))
            @foreach(session('cart') as $id => $details)
                @php $total += $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] @endphp
                <tr data-id="{{ $id }}">
                    <td data-th="Product">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><img src="{{ $details['image'] }}" width="100" height="100" class="img-responsive"/></div>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <h4 class="nomargin">{{ $details['name'] }}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Price">${{ $details['price'] }}</td>
                    <td data-th="Quantity">
                        <input type="number" value="{{ $details['quantity'] }}" class="form-control quantity update-cart" />
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="Subtotal" class="text-center">${{ $details['price'] * $details['quantity'] }}</td>
                    <td class="actions" data-th="">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-from-cart"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-right"><h3><strong>Total ${{ $total }}</strong></h3></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="text-right">
                <a href="{{ url('/') }}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Continue Shopping</a>
                <button class="btn btn-success">Checkout</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
@endsection
  
@section('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
  
    $(".update-cart").change(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  
        var ele = $(this);
  
        $.ajax({
            url: '{{ route('update.cart') }}',
            method: "patch",
            data: {
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', 
                id: ele.parents("tr").attr("data-id"), 
                quantity: ele.parents("tr").find(".quantity").val()
            },
            success: function (response) {
               window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
  
    $(".remove-from-cart").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
  
        var ele = $(this);
  
        if(confirm("Are you sure want to remove?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ route('remove.from.cart') }}',
                method: "DELETE",
                data: {
                    _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}', 
                    id: ele.parents("tr").attr("data-id")
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        }
    });
  
</script>
@endsection
```

6-public/css/style.css

```
.thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.thumbnail img {
    width: 80%;
}
.thumbnail .caption{
    margin: 7px;
}
.main-section{
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
}
.dropdown{
    float:right;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.btn{
    border:0px;
    margin:10px 0px;
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
.dropdown .dropdown-menu{
    padding:20px;
    top:30px !important;
    width:350px !important;
    left:-110px !important;
    box-shadow:0px 5px 30px black;
}
.total-header-section{
    border-bottom:1px solid #d2d2d2;
}
.total-section p{
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.cart-detail{
    padding:15px 0px;
}
.cart-detail-img img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding-left:15px;
}
.cart-detail-product p{
    margin:0px;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:500;
}
.cart-detail .price{
    font-size:12px;
    margin-right:10px;
    font-weight:500;
}
.cart-detail .count{
    color:#C2C2DC;
}
.checkout{
    border-top:1px solid #d2d2d2;
    padding-top: 15px;
}
.checkout .btn-primary{
    border-radius:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.dropdown-menu:before{
    content: " ";
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
    right:50px;
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#fff;
}
```